# How does hibernate handle cache expiry?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching

I'm using JPA with hibernate provider. A `@NamedQuery` uses the 
*hint: `hints = { @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.CACHEABLE, value = "true")`*

Since I couldn't find a way to define the expiration of the cache items, I assume that hibernate applies a default cache expiration mechanism.

How does this default mechanism work and when are the cache items discarded?

Comment: When the transaction is closed, it clears its cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kinds of configuration are cache provider specific. For example, this is the way to do it in [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/data-life).

Comment: Thx, but I want to know it for hibernate. I couldn't find any eplanation so far.

Comment: I'm telling you for Hibernate. :) Hibernate uses the [provider](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html#caching-provider-table) which you configure. It does not implement an L2 cache provider of its own (well, except of the HashTable which is for testing purposes only).